# creating schema with a table containing serial field

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I create (in a single SQL command) a schema and a table in it, but with the table containing a serial column (in Postgres) ?

For example, here I am attempting to create schema `zoo` with table `animals` from type `animal_t` with serial column `animal_id`:

```
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS animal_t CASCADE;
CREATE TYPE animal_t AS (
    animal_id           integer,
    animal_name         varchar
);
CREATE SCHEMA zoo
    CREATE TABLE animals OF animal_t 
        animal_id WITH OPTIONS NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('animals_animal_id_seq')
    CREATE SEQUENCE animals_animal_id_seq OWNED by animals.animal_id
;
```

Notes:

- `CREATE SCHEMA` only accepts `CREATE TABLE` or `CREATE SEQUENCE`, it does not accept `ALTER` , this is why I have to do all of this in a single SQL sentence.

Result:

```
-bash-4.3$ psql dev < animal.sql 
DROP TYPE
CREATE TYPE
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "animal_id"
LINE 3:   animal_id WITH OPTIONS NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('animals_a...
          ^
-bash-4.3$
```

Comment: @GrishaLevit but I can't remove it because I need to set the options with `CREATE TABLE` sentence. Or how would I set 'DEFAULT' otherwise? I am following the syntax of CREATE TABLE and it is OK to set field options.

Comment: Sorry my earlier comment was wrong.  But the syntax error is that you need parentheses, like: `... OF animal_t (animal_id WITH OPTIONS ...)`.  This doesn't really fix your problem but might get you on the right track.

Comment: Why are you over-complicating things? Why not simply: `create schema zoo; create table zoo.animals (animal_id serial primary key, animal_name varchar);`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name because in production I am not using a single schema, I am using many different schemas, which are created automatically. To avoid concatenating schema name with company_id I prefer create everything in a single `CREATE SCHEMA` sentence where you can use table names without prefixing schema name.

Comment: Again: if you use a serial, you _can_ do that in a single statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , unfortunately no, my other `PL`s use user-defined types to return data from this table, so to avoid copying data definition I must create the table as from a `TYPE`

Comment: I have no idea what your "other PLs" means - but you can use a table name just like an object type. In fact if you create a table, you _also_ create a type of that name.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , thanks , problem solved then. I can use table name as TYPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

1. simplify your statement and get rid of the object type

```
CREATE SCHEMA zoo
  CREATE table animal
  (
    animal_id    serial,
    animal_name  varchar
  );
```

2. use a search path if you want to avoid to prefix the table with a schema name:

```
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS animal_t CASCADE;
CREATE TYPE animal_t AS (
    animal_id           integer,
    animal_name         varchar
);

CREATE SCHEMA zoo;
set search_path = zoo;

CREATE SEQUENCE animals_animal_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE animals OF animal_t 
        animal_id WITH OPTIONS NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('animals_animal_id_seq');
alter sequence animals_animal_id_seq owned by animals.animal_id;
```

After creating the type and the schema, the current schema is set to the just created one, so all subsequent statements use `zoo` as the default schema.

Note that you can do this in a single transaction if that is another reason for you to use the "extended" create schema syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should do it.  The idea is to `ALTER` *schema_name.thing*:

```
CREATE SCHEMA zoo
  CREATE TABLE animals OF animal_t ( animal_id WITH OPTIONS NOT NULL )
;
CREATE SEQUENCE zoo.animals_animal_id_seq OWNED BY zoo.animals.animal_id;
ALTER TABLE zoo.animals ALTER animal_id SET DEFAULT nextval('zoo.animals_animal_id_seq');
```

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to do this without the `ALTER` , in a single SQL command?

Comment: I don't think so, because you need to create the sequence before you can use it in `DEFAULT nextval()`.